# Creating Data Input for Dynamic Table [Monthly Spending Tracker]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet that has Sheet1 for Data Entry and Sheet2 to display those values. But it gets a little more complicated as I want there to be a month dropdown menu in Sheet1 "Jan,Feb,Mar" etc... and based on that month, the table for data entry would update itself with either already existing values or values to add. It is for monthly spending tracker so there would be columns: Date | Name | Data Validation for Category | Amount. I will attach some pictures to help describe it.

Data Entry Sheet

[image]

Display Sheet

[image]

To make it even more clear:

[image]

Data validation on JAN to go through all the months and getting different results based on different month. But, I would like to edit whatever is inside that, if it's possible?

Could I maybe get some sample documents to see how it works?

Comment: You'll likely have to create some "helper" columns or ranges that filter the data into what you're looking for. Those filters can be dynamic and change based on your data, so "dynamic named ranges" will probably also be used. Look into those topics and see what you come up with, then you can ask a more detailed question with your attempts and formulas.

Comment: If you could explain a little more in detail what should I do? I tried looking for "dynamic named ranges" but couldnt find anything that would help me with what I am trying to do.

Comment: Search for how to create a drop-down on your cells with Data Validation (which you've already done) with a dynamic named range (there are MANY examples on the web). That dynamic named range will change based on some logic you mentioned in your post, but didn't fully explain. Working out the details of the dynamic range will make it more clear to you.

Comment: I don't want to just preview the data I've input. I want to change the month say - JAN - blank table shows up - I fill it up with data and that data is being shown on Sheet2. Then if I change the month to FEB, same thing happens and I can swap between them and change the data and so forth.

Comment: Then what I think you really need is a pivot table. What you're describing is perfectly served by a pivot table. There are [many](https://www.educba.com/pivot-table-in-excel/), [many](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/how-to-create-pivot-table-tutorial-ht), [many](https://www.guru99.com/pivot-tables-in-excel-beginner-s-guide.html) websites that can show you how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Pivot table shows the data based on another sheet, that's not something I want, I want to be able to choose a month, input the data there and see it in my display sheet mentioned above.